# `[$injector:nomod] Module 'google-maps' is not available`

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I'm using angular-google-maps to handle google maps at an angular application. For this, I have to add the `angular-google-maps.js`to the project.
The page works without any error, if I add the script in the following way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://www.directiv.es/application/html/js/nlaplante/angular-google-maps/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
```

But it will not work, if I use the local copy, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="js/libs/directiv.es/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
```

Looking at firebug, I see the `angular-google-maps.js` file is loaded, but in this case, the following error occurs:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module mapsApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module google-maps due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'google-maps' is not available! You either misspelled the...<omitted>...1)
```

Searching the web for hours I did not find any reason or solution. Maybe you have an idea or hint, how to find the reason?

Comment: Did  you make sure that the angular-google-maps.js file is loaded before you instantiate your angular module?

Comment: I have tried with an timeout for 2 sec before "bootstrap" the application. But no change. Instancing the angular module happens after bootstrap the application, right?  and: loading the `.js ` file from http should be much slower than linking to the local version. But the local version fails. Make that sense?

Comment: Did you created folder "directiv.es" with dot? as you are included that way <script type="text/javascript" 
        src="js/libs/directiv.es/angular-google-maps.js"></script>

Comment: Yes,the folder was created with dot! Looking at the firebug I see, that the `angular-google-maps.js` file is loaded without any problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution and like to write down that here for the case, the someone runs into the same problem.

In my case, I downloaded the angular-google-maps extension from github, extracted that zip-file on windows an copied the file to my project. With the result, that an error occurs: `Failed to instantiate module google-maps due to ...` while loading "the same" js file over http everything works fine. The point is: it's not the same file!

The solution is to take the file from the URL Link and storing local:

Maybe during downloading or extracting, the zip-file was broken. Maybe there is an character problem. Whatever.

If I open that link  `http://www.directiv.es/application/html/js/nlaplante/angular-google-maps/angular-google-maps.js` in an browser, I can right-click that file and open the source in an "source-code" editor and save that file on disk.

Now I can copy that new created file into my project folder like that location: `js/libs/directiv.es/angular-google-maps.js` and everything works fine.....